# Adding <br> tag inside a div tag failed

Tags: html

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="welcomename">
    <h1>Welcome! What's your name?</h1>
    <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
<br>
```

That works absolutely perfectly, but I for reasons, I need that `<br>` inside the `div 'welcomename`'. When I do this though, it doesn't work.

Other code:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
    <h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
    <form id="welcomehowareyou2" method="post">
        <select name="mood" onchange="popup(this.options.selectedIndex)">
            <option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
            <option>I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
            <option>I'm fine, but could be better</option>
            <option>I feel absolutely terrible today.</option>
            <!--<input type="submit" value="Done!"/>-->
    </form>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check with fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ghxce8dr/ 
It is working fine. I added `<p></p>` for both div.

```
<div id="welcomename">
    <h1>Welcome! What's your name?</h1>
    <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
<p></p>
Text After First Break
<div id="hiddenDiv">
    <h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
    <select name="mood" onchange="popup(this.options.selectedIndex)">
            <option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
            <option>I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
            <option>I'm fine, but could be better</option>
        <option>I feel absolutely terrible today.</option></select>
            <!--<input type="submit" value="Done!"/>-->    
    <p></p>
        Text After Second Break
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: <p></p> seemed to work, but I've got another div which it won't work in - I'll edit my comment and add it in.

Comment: as someone suggested in previous comments, you can place empty `div` as well `<div></div>` and place your `<br />` or `<p></p>` in that div

Comment: can you check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ghxce8dr/  ? Its working fine i think.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Thank you, that fiddle solved my question! Would it be possible for you to write it an answer, so I can mark it as the solver to my problem?

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the "br" just before the closing of the div and after the input element right? It is because the input element is an inline element.

Comment: When you add the br just before the closing of the div, it gets placed besides the input element as it is an inline element.

Comment: How would I prevent this?

Comment: Simply add a blank div,then put br. div is a block level element.

Comment: Like <div><br></div>?

Comment: First tell me why are you adding br tag?

Comment: In my opinion my website looks better with a space at the bottom.

Comment: @JugglingBob Sarath is right here but well...use padding and margin for space, not line breaks! It's not a typewriter...

Comment: I have got 10px padding on my site, but it doesn't work for forms.

Comment: It does, if not then I'd post that code to solve *that* problem!

Comment: So you're not getting space below the div? There is something wrong, i cant say without seeing the output. Anyway, add margin-bottom to the div with id hiddenDiv

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I've added that code now.